# ImportError: cannot import name 'has_pattern' from 'gensim.utils'

Tags: python, gensim

I trying to import gensim.

But I got this error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'has_pattern' from 'gensim.utils' (C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py)
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Check the Gensim version. if its lower, upgrade the package..

Answer (score 2):

Installing Version `3.4.0` solved the problem. Try the following :-

```
pip install gensim==3.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have gensim installed in your **development environment** along with its dependencies i.e. numpy, scipy and pattern:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gensim
conda install numpy
conda install -c anaconda scipy
conda install -c conda-forge pattern
```

If it's still not fixed then try updating conda:

```
conda update --all
```

also

```
conda update gensim
```

Maybe this would fix your issue!